# requests.post() doesn't aknowledge a response in Docker image only if request takes longer than 5 minutes

Tags: python, docker, python-requests

I have a docker image that makes a request to a web server that I have, which runs a machine learning pipeline using `requests.post(<endpoint>, json = req_obj)`. My pipeline runs in Databricks and when it's all said and done, it takes about 7.5 minutes from request to response.

When I make a request from within my docker image, if the response takes longer than 5 minutes, the response doesn't ever get acknowledged. The strange thing is that this only happens in docker and only if the response is longer than 5 minutes. If either of those conditions are changed, I get back exactly what I would expect.

I experimented with my pipline, doing nothing but having databricks return back the original JSON it was sent, but using `time.sleep()` to test time conditions. Setting it to pretty much anything I want and running it local instead of on docker doesn't impact what I would expect: I still get a response. I tested up to 10 minutes sleep and waiting for the response in a local terminal and I still got back the response. If I set it to sleep for 3 minutes and call it from python in docker, I get back a response. But when I run with `time.sleep(5*60)` in the pipeline and call from python in Docker, it just sits there; nothing happens. It's like it's in a coma. I have to `ctrl+c` to break out.

The docker image uses Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa).

Has anyone run into an issue with this before and found a solution? Does anyone have any things I can look into?

"use something other than Docker" is not an option, as we are shipping this to a vendor who can only use Docker.